# How to use OpenCV in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision

I have looked at many resources. I just want a simple way to use the newest OpenCV with Matlab 2017a. MinGW doesn't work and a compiler but I can't seem to get Visual C++ working. I can use OpenCV in Visual Studio but what compiler does Matlab want from me and how do I obtain it?

Comment: https://it.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-opencv.html or https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to use opencv from matlab without compiling any mex files, and without using the computer vision toolbox.

You can call opencv through matlab via python commands.

1) Download and install the CPython distribution, not Anaconda

2) from the command prompt, install the opencv and other packages you want using the pip command > python -m pip install opencv-python

3) Follow the procedure in the matlab help for ensuring matlab knows where to look for the python installation

4) use the syntax py.cv2.function to call the opencv function

If you keep the data types as python data types in matlab while using the py.cv2 functions there isn't too much of a speed hit.

Answer (score 1):

As @Miki mentions in the their comment, have you checked out [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-opencv.html) on the MathWorks site? It has many resources, the main one is the [Computer Vision System Toolbox OpenCV Interface](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47953-computer-vision-system-toolbox-opencv-interface). It comes with some examples which would be a good starting point. And if those aren't close to what you want, try another one of the [community examples](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=MATLAB%20OpenCV&utf8=%E2%9C%93) on the File Exchange and trying to make small changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

For each version of MATLAB you can find the supported compilers in the documentation. You can also use *-v* flag as shown blow to see all the paths where MATLAB looks for a C++ compiler.

```
mex -setup -v
```